# Why does my for loop to synchronize images run only once?

Tags: shell, variables, for-loop

Below script shall find all pictures from the source directory and its sub-directories and convert them with a lower resolution into the target directory, including the same sub-directory structure as the source directory.

All variables (like `FILELIST`, `DIRNAME`, `TFILENAME`) seem to list variables with the correct content.

The problem I have is that the for loop runs only once, therefore the variable `DSTPATH` (which shall have the correct destination path) only is correct in the first line and impacts as well the variable `TARGETFILE`.

This looks strange to me, as I'm in a loop.

```
#!/bin/sh
   
# must be with a /at the end
SRC=$1
DST=$2
FILELIST=`find $SRC -name '*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]'`
    
#for all files found
for SOURCEFILE in "$FILELIST"; do 
# Get same subdirectory as in source 
  DIRNAME=`echo "$SOURCEFILE" | awk -F '[^/]*$' '{print $1}'`
  SUBDIR=`echo "$DIRNAME" | awk -F "$SRC"  '{ if ( NF > 1 ) print $NF }'`

# check if destination directory not exists, if so create it
# build destination directory name first
  DSTPATH=${DST}"$SUBDIR"

  if [ ! -d "$DSTPATH" ]
    then
      echo "$DSTPATH will be created"
#      mkdir -p "$DSTPATH"
    else 
#     normaly not needed
      echo "$DSTPATH exists already"
  fi


# build up target filename
  TFILENAME=`echo "$SOURCEFILE" | awk -F '/' '{ if ( NF > 1 ) print $NF }'`
  TBASENAME=`echo "$TFILENAME" | awk -F '.' '{$NF=""; sub("[.]$",""); print $1}'`
  TEXT=`echo "$TFILENAME" | awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'`

  TARGETFILE=`echo "$DSTPATH""$TBASENAME""_p1080.""$TEXT"`

# now the files can be converted with convert
#  echo "Converting $SOURCEFILE to $TARGETFILE"

done
```

I do all string operations with `awk`, as for whatever reason `dirname` and `basename` do not work with my script either.

Comment: Your `for` loop has as only one argument. You can find these type of error easily by yourself, by running the program with `set -x`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for SOURCEFILE in "$FILELIST"; do
```

to:

```
for SOURCEFILE in $FILELIST; do
```

See this:

```
A="one two three"
for I in "$A"; do echo $I; done
for I in $A; do echo $I; done
```

according to basename, dirname issue, this should work:

```
TFILENAME=$(basename "$SOURCEFILE")
```

Comment: BTW, you can use find -iname '*.jpg' to perform case-Insensitive globbing.

Comment: Dear Michał,
thank you very much for you comments. 
Unfortunately both do no work.
I can't change to $FILELIST, because I have problems as the directory name contains spaces.
I tried the your comment with the basename. I get the reply "too many arguments". I assume the shell script works the whole time with the whole list and not per line item.

I'm still trying, if I have any news, I comment them.
BTW meanwhile I also figured out that TARGETFILE is incorect. I contains first all content of TBASENAME and afterwards all extentsion from TEXT.
thanks for additional help

Comment: @Scheini72 : If you have spaces in the filenames, I suggest that you don't use POSIX shell (where it is possible to handle this case, but cumbersome), but a shell which supports arrays (for instance zsh; other possibilities are ksh or bash, but in zsh dealing with spaces in filenames is IMHO easiest).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with filenames with spaces, try this:

```
FILE_LIST="name with spaces.jpg
another one.txt
one more.txt"
echo $FILE_LIST | while read LINE
do 
    echo "Filename is [$LINE]"
done
```

Note, that in this code, the loop is running in a subprocess (while is after "|").
You have access to (copy of) each global variable from outer scope, but changing them (copies in a loop) will have no effect in outer scope (after "done").

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works.
If you want, you might have a look to my answer

Comment: This makes `LINE` contain the concatenation of all three lines; a better solution would be an array. (Sorry for the comment 9 years later, just bumped into this ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot,

now it works and I can start resizing my images

See below the script how I use it for the moment. The next steps will be to optimize performance and logic, as this script runs on my NAS (low CPU and Memory performance, QNAP TS-219P)

```
#!/bin/sh

# must be with a /at the end
SRC=$1
DST=$2

# switch to working directory, for imagemagicks temp-path (will be changed later)
cd /share/Show_pictures/

# Temporary path used by imagemagick to convert images (dos not work so far)
  TMP_PATH=`echo "/share/share/Network Recycle Bin 1"`
# Get File list of source directory for converting
  FILELIST=`find $SRC -name '*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]'`
  echo "$FILELIST" > ./filelist

# for all files found
  echo "$FILELIST" | while read LINE
  do
#   Get same subdirectory as in source
    DIRNAME=`echo "$LINE" | /opt/bin/awk -F '[^/]*$' '{print $1}'`
    SUBDIR=`echo "$DIRNAME" | /opt/bin/awk -F "$SRC"  '{ if ( NF > 1 ) print $NF; else print "nothing" }'`

#   check if destination directory not exists, if so create it
#   build destination directory name first
    DSTPATH="$DST""$SUBDIR"
    if [ ! -d "$DSTPATH" ]
      then
        echo "$DSTPATH will be created"
        mkdir -p "$DSTPATH"
#     else
#       normaly not needed
#       echo "$DSTPATH exists already"
    fi

#  build up target filename
   TFILENAME=`echo "$LINE" | /opt/bin/awk -F '/' '{ if ( NF > 1 ) print $NF; else print "nothing" }'`
   TBASENAME=`echo "$TFILENAME" | /opt/bin/awk -F '.' '{$NF=""; sub("[.]$",""); print $1}'`
   TEXT=`echo "$TFILENAME" | /opt/bin/awk -F '.' '{print $NF}'`
   TARGETFILE=`echo "$DSTPATH""$TBASENAME""_p1080.""$TEXT"`
#  now the files can be converted with convert
#  but only it target file does not exist already (later check with difference by iamgemagick)
    if [ ! -f "$TARGETFILE" ]
      then
        echo "Converting $LINE to $TARGETFILE"
#       convert usage of imagemagick
        /opt/bin/convert -define registry:temporary-path="$TMP_PATH" -define jpeg:size=5200x5200 "$LINE" -auto-orient -resize '>1920x1080' "$TARGETFILE"
      else
        echo "$TARGETFILE exists already"
    fi
done
```